# How should I identify tense in the given sentence?

Tags: tense

> The electric violinist put the speaker on full blast and **shaken** up the house.

A. NO CHANGE

B. shook

C. had shook

D. begun to shake

Here put and blash are in present, so I eliminated B, A, and C. begun is a past participle, so I eliminated D. Well, there is no other answer choice left. The correct answer is B. Please help me with this question.

Comment: *Put* isn't a present; if it were, it would be *puts* due to subject–verb agreement (the subject is in the singular). Try to think about the sentence again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Blast" is being used as a noun in this sentence and so has no tense.

"Put" is an irregular verb and has "put" as its past and past participle.

If "put" were in the present tense in your sentence, it would be "puts" because it is in the third person. So the verb "put" is in the past tense.

Therefore the verb "shake" must also be in the past tense, and that verb too is irregular, with "shook" as the proper form,

Tricky question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, although B is the most likely answer, D is also possible.

In this case, attention is being drawn to the very first part of his performance, and it is implied that he (or she) continued to shake up the house.

Comment: *The electric violinist **begun** to shake up the house?* Are you sure it's not *began* that's the past simple form of the verb *to begin*?

Comment: @CookieMonster - Ooops. Dang my lying eyes. Can't tell the difference between u and a. Thanks for the correction. I'll delete this answer in a few hours.